# is it possible to insert into a table from a variable?

Tags: sql-server, dmv

Suppose i have two tables:

Table 1 (`$SYSTEM.DISCOVER_SESSIONS`) has columns A, B, C

Table 2 has columns A, C, D

I query table 1 to `select` data from columns A and C

I save that query result in a variable called: `$result`

essentially it looks like this:

`$result = 'SELECT [A],[C] FROM $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_SESSIONS'`

Now i want to `INSERT` `$result` in table 2, with columns automatically matching (A, C) since these were the ones stored in `$result`

I realized I could potentially use JOINS for this, but I am unsure how I can formulate the correct syntax for what Im trying to do.

```
INSERT INNER JOIN SELECT *
INTO table2 
FROM $result
```

Is the approach Im trying to do possible?

Comment: Are you using dynamic SQL for `$result`?

Comment: @alans well, i suppose $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_SESSIONS is a rowset which is from what i learned a Dynamic Management View, so perhaps yes...

Comment: So it's a view then. If so, just do an insert-select method: `insert into table2 ([A],[C]) select [A],[C] from $system.discover_sessions`. If you're outputing the result into a table variable, `$result`, do a insert-select against that. if `$result` is a dynamic sql, `insert into table2 ([A],[C]) sp_executesql ($result)`

Comment: @alans yes i could do it that way, but i am already querying the view to export to excel file before i want to insert the results into table2 as well. which is why I dont want to repeat the selection specific columns and instead use the $result variable that i already stored the select query in

Comment: So the columns in `$result` can change, and you want the columns to match. I see.

Comment: @alans correct. this is why i dont want to specify columns and instead somehow join whatever columns are selected to match columns in table2

Comment: But how are you going to match A,B,C,D to X,Y,Z????

Comment: @SlavaMurygin exactly. JOIN will make sure that if the columns dont exist in table2, then no columns are inserted

Comment: Sorry, I still think that you have to tag it for PowerShell, because the code is mostly there.

Comment: @SlavaMurygin maybe if i include the export csv part...

Comment: Does not matter. you are asking about "insert". You have to provide SQL table specification and specify what you are trying to insert. As of now, it is not clear.